# Can Bing Spatial Data Services be accessed programatically via C#?

Tags: c#, geocoding, latitude-longitude, bing-maps

I read about Bing Spatial Data Services [here](http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2014/10/09/how-to-add-custom-auto-complete-functionality-to-your-map-app/), where a jQuery example is given.

I'd like to know if BSDS can be accessed programatically via C#. I'd like to pass it data in a file in some common format (such as csv or xml), and get it back with the longitude and latitude elements populated. Is this possible?

Comment: Sure, why not? You could use a WebRequest for that.

Comment: More specifics would be appreciated (how to do it exactly, such as an example or pseudocode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Bing Spatial Data Services is a REST based web service and can be accessed from any programming language that supports connections to the web. If you just want to do batch Geocoding, this can be done using the Geocode Dataflow API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701733.aspx There is a c# sample in the documentation. Note, that if you are using this service using a basic or trial account you will be limited to 50 rows of data per upload. If you have a licensed Enterprise account you can upload 200,000 rows of data per file, and up to 25 files in a 24 hour period.